# Logic Pro X not playing most software instruments

Tags: midi, logic-pro, mac

So, I've been using Logic Pro X for some years now, but since I updated my MacOS I've come across an issue I never had before.

Before updating my MacOS, Logic Pro X was working fine; I was mostly using software instruments (the ones you can download directly from Logic itself, no additional libraries).

**After swapping my HDD for an SSD and updating to Catalina OS, Logic started asking to download additional content every time** I opened it; strangely enough, it never actually "finished" downloading anything. It kinda did, and it **spent hours downloading tons of stuff, but once I started the program again, it asked to download the exact same things**.

As this was getting a bit annoying, I decided to tinker around and try to solve it myself. I guessed the libraries were outdated, something was not being updated properly, or something of the sort... so **I tried the following**:

1. **Deleted stuff in "Library/Application Support/Logic"**, following some thread I read, and assuming that this would force Logic to re-download all software instruments. Did not work.
2. **Deleted the Logic application, and re-installed again**. The program picked up at the same place, with the same issues. Did not work.
3. **Deleted Logic, deleted all stuff in "Library/Application Support/Logic"**, re-installed the program hoping to get a clean start. Logic asked to download all stuff, but reacted the same way as it did before trying any of the solutions. Did not work.
4. **Restored the Logic application and the content of the aforementioned "Library/Application Support/Logic" from an older Time Machine backup**, from a time when things run somewhat well... Did not work.

Now I'm at a point, after having tried these things, where **Logic not only keeps asking for downloading additional content, as it did before, but now MOST SOFTWARE INSTRUMENTS ARE NOT EVEN PLAYING**! When opening one of the first Logic projects I did, where I didn't use many fancy additional instruments, **it seems (not 100% sure of this theory, though) that the only software instruments being played are actually Garage Band instruments**:

- Retro Rock Kit (drums)
- Hard Rock (guitar)
- Glassy FM Lead (synth)
- Classic Electric Piano (electric piano)

However, I don't get any sound from any of these:

- Picked Bass (bass)
- French Horns (brass)
- Trumpets (brass)

Has anyone had similar issues as the ones I'm having, and managed to solve it? It's starting to drive me crazy as I can't actually work on any project whatsoever... Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Aside from upgrading the OS, I swapped and HDD for an SSD.

Comment: Which release of Logic Pro X are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 10.0.6 (sorry I forgot to mention in the main post)

Comment: Do you have the option of upgrading to the current release: 10.6.2?

Comment: Nope, I'm afraid I'm stuck with my current version... Got this one through a different user I have no access to now, so I'd have to buy it again. :___)

Comment: Here's a guess: you're using 32-bit software instruments. Catalina requires 64-bit code.

Comment: Mm that makes sense, but why was I able to keep using the instruments (despite Logic complaining over and over that it needed more content), and why I can't now? I've been using the same version, even after upgrading to Catalina...

Comment: I think the better question is whether you can find 64-bit instruments and if they solve the problem. Beyond that, I think I've gone as far as I can with this one.

Comment: Cheers Aaron, I'll dig around for 64-bit instrument to see if that solves the problem!

Comment: you can get 90-day free trial version of the latest Logic. You could try that to see if it's a 64-bit issue.